# Change canvas gradient object's properties

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d, gradient

```
var i = 0;
var x = 960;
var y = 540;
var interval = window.setInterval(render, 100);

function render()
{

gradient = cxt.createRadialGradient(x, y, i, x, y, i+10);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");//white inside 
gradient.addColorStop(.4, "rgba(255,255,255,1)");//white inside 
gradient.addColorStop(.6, "rgba(255,255,255,1)");//white inside 
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");//fade to transparent black outside;

cxt.fillStyle= "#000000";
cxt.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
cxt.fillStyle = gradient;
cxt.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
cxt.fill();
cxt.drawImage(logo,0,0);
i+=5;

}
```

I'm trying to animate a feathered loop expanding. 
This code is pretty inefficient, because I'm using the constructor to change as single property each loop. How can I change a single property that is passed as a parameter to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Canvas specs...

```
interface CanvasGradient {
  // opaque object
  void addColorStop(in float offset, in DOMString color);
};
```

...and earlier it says about fillStyle and strokeStyle...

> On getting, if the value is a color,
>   then the serialization of the color 
>   must be returned. Otherwise, if it is
>   not a color but a CanvasGradient or 
>   CanvasPattern, then the respective
>   object must be returned. (Such objects
>   are opaque and therefore only useful
>   for assigning to other attributes or
>   for comparison to other gradients or
>   patterns.)

Lastly, introspecting a gradient just reveals the addColorStop function.

So I think the constructor is the only place those values can be set; but are you sure the constructor is really slowing it down? If your animation is slow maybe it's something else. Have you timed it?